# Chip-8 Emulator in Zsh

Tags: bash, virtual-machine, zsh

I've spent the last few weeks writing a Chip-8 emulator in zsh. It doesn't run in bash but the syntax is nearly identical. I have it on a GitHub repo here: https://github.com/hcorion/chipzsh a snapshot at the time of writing this is [here](https://github.com/hcorion/chipzsh/tree/b09d2d3575cd8bc25f0d82595950f9190bfb125e).
I believe I need to post the full code here. So here it goes.

```
#! /usr/bin/env zsh

# Copyright (C) 2017 Zion Nimchuk

# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.

# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.

# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

## I made it easier on myself and used the following shell utilities:
## - od command for reading the binary from the file.


# Ksh arrays start at 0, and the chip-8 register access starts at 0. It makes things simpler.
setopt KSH_ARRAYS

########################################
##               TESTS                ##
########################################

if [ ! -f input.txt ]
then
    echo "The file input.txt was not found, the emulator will still run fine, but will not accept any input from your keyboard."
    echo "If you did want input, just run the input.zsh file in another window."
    echo "If you don't want input, type in any key to continue. If you do want input, just type Ctrl+C and run the input.zsh script."
    read -q
    input=no
fi


# Detecting for input for a rom file from the user.
inputName=""
if [ -z $1 ]
then
    echo "No ROM file name was given. You can pass it as an argument like $0 romname.ch8"
    echo "You can also just type in the name of the ROM you want to use right now."
    echo "Enter ROM Name: "
    read fileName
    inputName=$fileName
else
    inputName=$1
fi

if [ ! -f $inputName ]; then
    echo "File $inputName not found! Stopping script."
    exit
fi

declare -a inputfile
# Reading input from file
LC_ALL=C inputfile=($(od -t x1 -An ${inputName}))

########################################
## SETTING UP THE VARIABLES           ##
########################################

# The program counter starts at 0x200 (512)
PC=512

# There is also an index register! Hooray!
# The index register is 16-bit!
I=0

# We also need a stack, hooray!
declare -a stack
# Aaand a stack pointer 
sp=1

# There are 15 general purpose registers.
# There is also a 16th register for carry operations.
# All 16 registers are 8-bit, ie max 255
declare -a reg
for i in {1..16}
do
    reg+=(0)
done

echo "registers: ${#reg[@]}"

# The screen is 64x32 pixels (2048)
declare -a screen
for i in {1..2048}
do
    screen+=(0)
done

# A timer used for delaying of things.
delayTimer=0
# The amount of cycles before delayTimer decrements, is readonly
declare -r waitTime=5
# This is decremented every turn, if it reaches 0, it is reset to $waitTime and delayTimer is decremented 1.
delayCycles=$waitTime

########################################
## SETTING UP THE RAM                 ##
########################################

declare -a fonts

fonts=(
        f0 90 90 90 f0 # 0
        20 60 20 20 70 # 1
        f0 10 f0 80 f0 # 2
        f0 10 f0 10 f0 # 3
        90 90 f0 10 10 # 4
        f0 80 f0 10 f0 # 5
        f0 80 f0 90 f0 # 6
        f0 10 20 40 40 # 7
        f0 90 f0 90 f0 # 8
        f0 90 f0 10 f0 # 9
        f0 90 f0 90 90 # A
        e0 90 e0 90 e0 # B
        f0 80 80 80 f0 # C
        e0 90 90 90 e0 # D
        f0 80 f0 80 f0 # E
        f0 80 f0 80 80 # F
)

declare -a ram

#Add the fonts to the ram. Exactly 80 characters (0x50)
for i in {0..${#fonts[@]}}
do
    ram+=(${fonts[$i]})
done

# data from 0x0 to 0x200 (512) is reserved for things. and we already added the font values (512-80=0x50). 
for i in {0..431}
do
    ram+=(0)
done
# The ROM information is copied to the RAM starting at 0x200 (512)
for i in {0..${#inputfile[@]}}
do
    ram+=(${inputfile[$i]})
done

# Fill up the rest of the rom.
for i in {0..$((3583 - ${#inputfile[@]}))}
do
    ram+=(0)
done

echo $ram
echo "RAM LENGTH: ${#ram[@]} (should be 4096)"


########################################
## MAIN LOOP                          ##
########################################


# I don't think bash does booleans properly, so 0 is not done and 1 is done.

# A variable to signify that the emulator needs to be stopped, usually set to 1 for unimplemented opcodes.
done=0
# A flag that is set whenever the screen needs to be drawn, because we don't need to draw every frame.
draw=0
# A debugging flag. Set this to 1 at any point in the code to have the emulator stop and wait for your input.
pause=0

while [ $done -eq 0 ]
do

    # Drawing the screen.
    if [ $draw -eq 1 ]
    then
        for i in {0..63}
        do
            fmt+="%s"
        done
        fmt+="\n"
        printf -v new "$fmt" "${screen[@]}"

        # Converting the 0s and 1s to a nice readable format.
        new=${new//1/██}
        echo "${new//0/  }"

        fmt=""
        draw=0
        echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    fi

    # There is no easy cross-platform way to calculate the time in nano-seconds, so we just have to fudge it.
    if [ $delayTimer -gt 0 ]
    then
        ((delayCycles-=1))
        if [ $delayCycles -le 0 ]
        then
            ((delayTimer-=1))
            delayCycles=$waitTime
        fi
    fi

    if [ $pause -eq 1 ]
    then
        pause=0
        echo "Press any key when your ready to proceed."
        read -q
    fi

    address=${ram[$PC]}

    case ${address:0:1} in
        (0)
            case ${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]} in
                (ee)
                    # Format: 00EE
                    # Returns from a subroutine.
                    ((sp-=1))
                    PC=${stack[$sp]}
                    ;;
                (e0)
                    # Format: 00E0
                    # Clears the screen.
                    for i in {0..${#screen[@]}}
                    do
                        screen[$i]=0
                    done
                    draw=1
                    ;;
                *)
                    echo "Error! Unimplemented 0 opcode (0xyz) called: ${address}${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]}"
                    done=1
                    ;;
            esac
            ;;
        (1)
            # Format: 1NNN
            # Jumps to address NNN.
            PC=$((16#${address:1:2}${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]:0:2}))
            ((PC-=2))
            ;;
        (2)
            # Format: 2NNN
            # Calls subroutine at NNN.
            stack[sp]=$PC
            ((sp++))
            PC=$((16#${address:1:2}${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]:0:2}))
            ((PC-=2))
            ;;
        (3)
            # Format: 3XNN
            # Skips the next instruction if data register X is equal to NN. 
            register=${reg[$((16#${address:1:2}))]}

            if [ $register -eq $((16#${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]:0:2})) ]
            then
                ((PC+=2))
            fi
            ;;
        (4)
            # Format: 4XNN
            # Skips the next instruction if data register X is not equal to NN. 
            register=${reg[$((16#${address:1:2}))]}

            if [ $register -ne $((16#${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]:0:2})) ]
            then
                ((PC+=2))
            fi
            ;;
        (6)
            # Format: 6XNN
            # Sets data register X to NN.
            nextAddress=${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]:0:2}

            reg[$((16#${address:1:2}))]=$((16#${nextAddress}))
            ;;
        (7)
            # Format: 7XNN
            # Adds NN to data register X.
            toAdd=$((16#${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]:0:2}))
            x=$((16#${address:1:2}))
            #echo "Adding $toAdd to data register #$regAddress which is $reg[$regAddress]"
            added=`expr $toAdd + ${reg[$x]}`

            # The & 255 makes sure the variable overflows properly.
            reg[$x]=$(($added & 255))
            ;;
        (8)
            # The mega math opcode
            nextAddress=${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]}
            case ${nextAddress:1:2} in
                (0)
                    # Format 8XY0
                    # Sets register X to register Y.
                    x=$((16#${address:1:2}))
                    y=$((16#${nextAddress:0:1}))
                    reg[$x]=${reg[$y]}
                    ;;
                (1)
                    # Format 8XY1
                    # Sets register X to register X OR rgister Y.
                    x=$((16#${address:1:2}))
                    y=$((16#${nextAddress:0:1}))
                    reg[$x]=$((${reg[$x]} | ${reg[$y]}))
                    ;;
                (2)
                    # Format 8XY2
                    # Sets register X to register X AND register Y. (Bitwise AND operation)
                    x=$((16#${address:1:2}))
                    y=$((16#${nextAddress:0:1}))

                    reg[$x]=$((${reg[$x]} & ${reg[$y]}))
                    ;;
                (3)
                    # Format 8XY3
                    # Sets register X to register X XOR register Y. (Bitwise XOR operation)
                    x=$((16#${address:1:2}))
                    y=$((16#${nextAddress:0:1}))
                    reg[$x]=$((${reg[$x]} ^ ${reg[$y]}))
                    ;;
                (4)
                    # Format 8XY4
                    # Adds register Y to register X. Register 16 (carry flag) is set to 1 when there's a carry, and to 0 when there isn't.
                    x=$((16#${address:1:2}))
                    y=$((16#${nextAddress:0:1}))

                    added=`expr ${reg[$x]} + ${reg[$y]}`

                    # We need to implement integer overflow.
                    if [ $added -gt 255 ]
                    then
                        reg[15]=1
                    else
                        reg[15]=0
                    fi

                    # The & 255 makes sure the variable overflows properly.
                    reg[$x]=$(( $added & 255))
                    ;;
                (5)
                    # Format 8XY5
                    # register Y is subtracted from register X. register 16 (carry flag) is set to 0 when there's a borrow, and 1 when there isn't.
                    x=$((16#${address:1:2}))
                    y=$((16#${nextAddress:0:1}))

                    sub=`expr ${reg[$x]} - ${reg[$y]}`

                    # We need to implement integer overflow.
                    if [ ${reg[$x]} -gt ${reg[$y]} ]
                    then
                        reg[15]=1
                    else
                        reg[15]=0
                    fi

                    # The & 255 makes sure the variable overflows properly.
                    reg[$x]=$(( $sub & 255))
                    ;;
                (6)
                    # Format 8XY6
                    # Shifts register X right by one. Register 16 (carry flag) is set to the value of the least significant bit of VX before the shift.
                    x=$((16#${address:1:2}))
                    y=$((16#${nextAddress:0:1}))

                    reg[15]=$((${reg[$x]} & 1))
                    reg[$x]=$((${reg[$x]} >> 1))
                    ;;
                (e)
                    # Format 8XYe
                    # Shifts register X left by one. Register 16 (carry flag) is set to the value of the most significant bit of VX before the shift.
                    x=$((16#${address:1:2}))
                    y=$((16#${nextAddress:0:1}))

                    reg[15]=$((${reg[$x]} & 128))
                    reg[$x]=$((${reg[$x]} << 1))
                    ;;
                *)
                    done=1
                    echo "Error! Unimplemented math opcode (8xyz) called: ${address}${nextAddress}"
                    ;;
            esac

            ;;
        (9)
            # Format: 9XY0
            # Skips the next instruction if register X doesn't equal register Y.
            nextAddress=${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]}

            x=${reg[$((16#${address:1:2}))]}
            y=${reg[$((16#${nextAddress:0:1}))]}

            if [ $x -ne $y ]
            then
                ((PC+=2))
            fi
            ;;
        (a)
            # Format: ANNN
            # Sets I to the address NNN.
            I=$((16#${address:1:2}${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]:0:2}))
            ;;
        (c)
            # Format: CXNN
            # Set register X = random byte AND NN.
            random=$(( RANDOM % 255 ))
            nextAddress=$((16#${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]}))
            reg[$((16#${address:1:2}))]=$(($random & $nextAddress))
            ;;
        (d)
            # Format: DXYN
            # Pixel drawing. 
            nextAddress=${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]}
            height=$((16#${nextAddress:1:2}))
            x=$((16#${address:1:2}))
            y=$((16#${nextAddress:0:1}))
            reg[15]=0

            for (( row=0; row<$height; row++ ))
            do
                sprite=$((16#${ram[`expr $I + $row`]}))
                for col in {0..7}
                do
                    test=$((${sprite} & 128))
                    if [ $test -gt 0 ]
                    then
                        xpos=$(( ${reg[$(($x))]} + $col))
                        ypos=$(( ${reg[$(($y))]} + $row))

                        if [ $ypos -ge 32 ]
                        then
                            rows=3
                            while [ $ypos -ge $row ]
                            do
                                ((ypos-=1))
                            done
                        fi

                        columns=64
                        if [ $xpos -ge 64 ]
                        then
                            while [ $xpos -ge $columns ]
                            do
                                ((xpos-=1))
                            done
                        fi
                        location=$(($xpos + ( $ypos * $columns ) ))
                        if [ $location -gt 2048 ]
                        then
                            done=1
                            echo "Error! The location to set the pixel was greater than the screen size."
                            echo "location: $location"
                            echo "ypos: $ypos"
                            echo "xpos: $xpos"
                        fi

                        screen[location]=$((${screen[$location]} ^ 1))
                        if [ ${screen[$location]} -eq 0 ]
                        then
                            reg[15]=1
                        fi
                    fi
                    sprite=$(($sprite << 1))
                done
            done
            draw=1
            ;;
        (e)
            # Format: EX9E or EXA1
            nextAddress=${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]}
            if [ "$nextAddress" = "9e" ]
            # Skips the next instruction if the key stored in register X is pressed.
            then
                # TODO: ACTUALLY implement
                # I haven't found a ROM that uses this yet, so I'm leaving it unimplemented.
                done=1
                echo "Error! Opcode EX9E was called but has not yet been implemented."

            elif [ "$nextAddress" = "a1" ]
            # Skips the next instruction if the key stored in register X isn't pressed.
            then

                # We need to check if the user has input set-up properly.
                if [ -z "$input" ]
                then
                    key=${reg[$((16#${address:1:2}))]}
                    fileInput=$(<input.txt)
                    if [ -z "$fileInput" ]
                    then
                        ((PC+=2))
                    elif [ $fileInput -ne $key ]
                    then
                        ((PC+=2))
                        echo "" > input.txt
                    else
                        echo "" > input.txt
                    fi
                fi
            else
                done=1
                echo "Error! Unimplemented E opcode (Exyz) called: ${address}${nextAddress}"
            fi
            ;;
        (f)
            # The opcode to rule them all!
            case ${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]:0:2} in
                (07)
                    # Format: FX07
                    # Sets register X to delayTimer
                    reg[$((16#${address:1:2}))]=$delayTimer
                    ;;
                (15)
                    # Format: FX15
                    # Sets delayTimer to register X
                    delayTimer=${reg[$((16#${address:1:2}))]}
                    ;;
                (18)
                    # Format: FX18
                    # Something to do with sound
                    # TODO: Actually implement
                    ;;
                (29)
                    # Format: FX29
                    # Sets I to the location of the sprite for the character in VX. Characters 0-F (in hexadecimal) are represented by a 4x5 font.
                    data=$((16#${address:1:2}))

                    # I is an unsigned 16-bit value, so we don't need to worry about overflow here.
                    I=$((${reg[$data]} * 5))
                    ;;
                (33)
                    # Format FX33
                    # Store BCD representation of register X in memory locations I, I+1, and I+2.
                    # Here is a good explanation: https://github.com/AfBu/haxe-CHIP-8-emulator/wiki/(Super)CHIP-8-Secrets#understanding-of-store-bcd-instruction
                    number=${reg[$((16#${address:1:2}))]}

                    # All values stored in RAM need to be hex, so we need to convert it back into hexadecimal.
                    printf -v hex "%x" $(( $number / 100 ))
                    ram[$I]=$hex

                    printf -v hex "%x" $(( $number % 100 / 10 ))
                    ram[(($I + 1))]=$hex

                    printf -v hex "%x" $(( $number % 10 ))
                    ram[(($I + 2))]=$hex
                    ;;
                (55)
                    # Format: FX55
                    # Stores Register 0 to Register X (including X) in memory starting at address I.
                    #echo "reg before" $reg
                    for i in {0..$((16#${address:1:2}))}
                    do
                        #reg[$i]=$((16#$ram[`expr $I + $i - 1`]))
                        printf -v hex "%x" ${reg[$i]}
                        ram[$(($I + $i))]=$hex
                    done
                    ;;
                (65)
                    # Format: FX65
                    # Fills data register 0 to X (including X) with values from memory starting at address I.
                    #echo "reg before" $reg
                    for i in {0..$((16#${address:1:2}))}
                    do
                        reg[$i]=$((16#${ram[`expr $I + $i`]}))
                    done
                    #echo "reg after" $reg
                    #((PC+=2))
                    ;;
                (1e)
                    # Format: FX1e
                    # Adds data register X to I
                    x=$((16#${address:1:2}))

                    added=`expr $I + ${reg[$x]}`

                    # We need to implement integer overflow.
                    if [ $added -gt 65535 ]
                    then
                        I=`expr $added - 65536`
                        reg[15]=1
                    else
                        I=$added
                        reg[15]=0
                    fi

                    ;;
                *)
                    echo "F is unimplemented. Calling: ${address:1:2}${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]}"
                    echo "Error! Unimplemented F opcode (Fxyz) called: ${address}${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]}"
                    done=1
                    ;;
            esac
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Error! Unimplemented opcode called: ${address}${ram[`expr $PC + 1`]}"
            done=1
            ;;
    esac

    ((PC+=2))
done

echo "Stats: "
echo "We went through $cycles cycles."
```

Comment: What are you looking for from the code review?

Comment: @chicks Just general improvement suggestions. Perhaps my code is using a slower way of doing things, and can actually be sped up by using X. Maybe the way I did X was kind of backwards and it would be much easier and more readable if I did Y. That kind of thing.